# Is it safe and good to show port number in URL?

Tags: security, web

I am having a nodejs server on port `3000` so to get the socket.io.js file i am using url like `localhost:3000/socket/io.....`

Is it safe and good to show port number in URL ?

Comment: I don't see why not; anybody could always determine a port that software is using by running a netstat command or software like ettercap. It's probably "safe and good", as long as the software running on that port is secure :)

Comment: let say my node server is down or stopped so port 300o is not being used so Can i use that port and hack

Comment: If there is no software running on that port, there is nothing to connect to, even if that port is "allowed" by your network security policy - so no! "Open Ports" are only scary because there may be exploitable software waiting for a connection to be made on that port. The software running is the problem, not the "port" itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's no more dangerous to reveal port number than it is IP address. E.g. discloses a very small amount of information about your network, but doesn't significantly degrade your security. And if you're relying on a 'hidden' port number for any sort of security, then you're making a mistake.

Comment: what is 'hidden' port?

Comment: You can run a service on any port. There are some that are officially published - like port 80 for a web server. You can run a webserver on a different port number 'hiding' it from anyone who doesn't know it's on a different port. But as a security measure, it's about on a par with putting your house key under the doormat.

Comment: To elaborate - this is exactly what port scanners are made for. They scan a particular range of ports on an address looking for one that has software running on it. If there is something to connect to, you can start experimenting with how to exploit it. In this case, "hidden" simply means not explicitly shown - it is still very easy to determine what port you're connecting to. Try it yourself in cmd prompt: type netstat -a